# Datetime string format alignment

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

In Python 2.7 I want to print datetime objects using string formatted template.  For some reason using left/right justify doesn't print the string correctly.

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 9, 0)
l = [dt, dt]
template = "{0:>25} {1:>25}" # right justify
print template.format(*l)  #print items in the list using template
```

This will result:

```
>25 >25
```

Instead of

```
  2013-06-26 09:00:00       2013-06-26 09:00:00
```

Is there some trick to making datetime objects print using string format templates?

It seems to work when I force the datetime object into str()

```
print template.format(str(l[0]), str(l[1]))
```

but I'd rather not have to do that since I'm trying to print a list of values, some of which are not strings.  The whole point of making a string template is to print the items in the list.

Am I missing something about string formatting or does this seem like a python bug to anyone?

---

**SOLUTION**

@mgilson pointed out the solution which I missed in the documentation. [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

> Two conversion flags are currently supported: '!s' which calls str()
>   on the value, and '!r' which calls repr().
>
> Some examples:

```
"Harold's a clever {0!s}"        # Calls str() on the argument first
"Bring out the holy {name!r}"    # Calls repr() on the argument first
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `datetime` objects have a `__format__` method which is basically just an alias for `datetime.strftime`.  When you do the formatting, the format function gets passed the string `'>25'` which, as you've seen, `dt.strftime('>25')` just returns `'>25'`.

The workaround here it to specify that the field should be formatted as a string explicitly using `!s`:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 9, 0)
l = [dt, dt]
template = "{0!s:>25} {1!s:>25} " 
out = template.format(*l)
print out
```

(tested on both python2.6 and 2.7).

Comment: I'll be darned. That's exactly what I needed.  


Found the one line in the documentation for this (which I missed). [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)  


_Two conversion flags are currently supported: '!s' which calls str() on the value, and '!r' which calls repr()._

Comment: @MarcelWilson -- I didn't know about this either until I went searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.datetime` has [**format** method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__format__). You need to convert it str.

```
>>> '{:%Y/%m/%d}'.format(dt)
'2013/06/26'
>>> '{:>20}'.format(dt)
'>20'
>>> '{:>20}'.format(str(dt))
' 2013-06-26 09:00:00'
```

---

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 9, 0)
>>> l = [dt, dt]
>>> template = "{0:>25} {1:>25}"
>>> print template.format(*l)
>25 >25
>>> print template.format(*map(str, l))
      2013-06-26 09:00:00       2013-06-26 09:00:00
```

Comment: That's what I did as a workaround until I read @mgilson's solution.  It just felt awkward to call str() when that's (afaik) what a stringformat template was supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print template.format(*map(str, l))
=>      2013-06-26 09:00:00       2013-06-26 09:00:00
```

It works by first converting the `datetime` objects to a string, which then can be formatted with the `format` method without problems.